# Cannot figure out the issue with this simple Angular contoller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and have a problem with a simple controller. Can anyone help me with that? I don't understand why the `SimpleController` does not work here!!!
I need the input of the text box be shown after the field as shown by `{{name}}`.
And basically it should produce a list of customers retrieved from `SimpleController' where this list should be filtered by`name`and ordered by`budget`...
But it does not!
Here is the Html and JS code:

```
<html ng-app="">
    <head>
       <title>My Angular with Simple Controller</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div ng-controller="SimpleController">
        Name: 
        <br />
        <input type="text" ng-model="name" /> {{name}}
        <br />
        <h3> Looping with ng-repeat & SimpleController</h3>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name | orderBy:'budget'">
                 {{cust.name}} - {{cust.city}} - {{cust.budget}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function SimpleController($scope) {
            $scope.customers = [
                {name: 'AAA', city:'cityAAA', budget:'500'},
                {name: 'BBB', city:'cityBBB', budget:'5000'},
                {name: 'ABC', city:'cityABC', budget:'6000'},
            ];
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

the scenario works fine without the use of controller ( by using only `ng-init`)

Comment: What error is thrown? Angular dropped support for global functions as controllers in version 1.3. What version are you using?

Comment: I dont think any error is thrown... but the desired output is not shown! my current version is AngularJS v1.5.8

Comment: follow docs to create module and register controller and implement both with ng-app

Answer (score 0):

Works fine when angular module is added.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/10009/)

Comment: I think as @charlietfl told, it is not anymore supported to include global functions as contollers in versions higher than 1.3
I should separate the view and the controller. I assume fiddle works the same way as well.